# jQuery Masonry with JavaScript Generated HTML won't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using [Masonry 4.2.2](https://masonry.desandro.com) from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/masonry) ([docs](https://github.com/desandro/masonry#masonry)), and [jQuery 3.5.0](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery).

I have JavaScript that uses an array and loop to generate HTML `grid-items` for Masonry.

The items appear, but they will not align horizontal like they're supposed to, they will only stack vertical.

---

https://jsfiddle.net/r8u0n6jk/

---

#### HTML

```
<div id="gallery" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 150 }'>
  <!-- Generated HTML -->
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.grid-item {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
// Gallery Item Array
var gallery = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];


// Generate Gallery List HTML
$(document).ready(Generate);

function Generate() {
  var list = document.getElementById("gallery");
  var html = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class=\"grid-item\">' + gallery[i] + '</div>';
  }

  list.innerHTML = html;
}


// Masonry
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gallery').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 150,
    isFitWidth: true,
  });
});
```

---

### Result

Stacks vertical

[image: result]

### Desired Effect

Should align horizontal and fluidly reposition on screen size change.

Working Example without JavaScript Generated HTML:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ys5k17p

[image: desired]

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline` property in css?

Comment: @RaviNain It does not seem work work, neither does `inline-block`. Masonry should apply the effect automatically.

Comment: You need to add that property in `.grid-item div { display:inline}`.

Comment: @RaviNain I have tried here https://jsfiddle.net/5zxrh3Lj

Comment: You are using same class name for both child and parent div.

Comment: This did work but you need to fix the width and height: `#gallery .grid-item {
  display: inline;
}`

Comment: @RaviNain I fixed the mistake, take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/q32v9yL0/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212319/discussion-between-ravi-nain-and-matt-mcmanis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following statement in css:

```
.grid-item div {
   display: inline
 }
```

Also, increase the column width:

```
// Masonry
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gallery').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 500,
    isFitWidth: true,
  });
});
```

Check example: https://jsfiddle.net/uszdtpb8/

Edit: See this example too: https://jsfiddle.net/hq0zLgfm/

Comment: It does not appear to be working properly. It should behave where the grid-items will fluidly rearrange and stack when the window size is changed, like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/3ys5k17p

Comment: I don't know if it's a CSS issue, it might be a jQuery loading issue.

Comment: You are trying to initialize Masonry twice: using html and jquery. Remove masonry initialization from html. It will work.
Checkout this example: https://jsfiddle.net/hq0zLgfm/

Comment: What I mean by removing masonry initialization from html is: remove `data-masonry` attribute from the div.

Comment: I removed the data-masonry. Thanks, that fixed the problem. I must have used the code from 2 different examples.